# How to get @ngtools/webpack to generate d.ts type declaration files?

Tags: webpack, angular-compiler, ngtools

I'm inching my lerna monorepo towards angular-cli (it's been a monumental undertaking) and unfortunately I need to build libraries with @ngtools/webpack instead of ng-packagr because it's too opinionated. I noticed that @ngtools/webpack does not generate type declaration because I assume it thinks the library, that is clearly marked as a library in angular.json, is an app. Anyway is there a setting I'm missing to get @ngtools/webpack to generate type declarations or do I have to run tsc with SpawnPlugin like I did with ts-loader?